# Django toolbar not showing by running with port

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-debug-toolbar

I'm developing a Django app on amazon ec2

I would like to use django-debug-toolbar
I've set every setting config in middleware installapp or another thing such as:

```
INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1','54.169.6.68','0.0.0.0','172.31.14.155',)
def custom_show_toolbar(self):
return True

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': True,
    'ENABLE_STACKTRACES' : True,
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': custom_show_toolbar,
}

DEBUG = True
CONFIG_DEFAULTS = {
    'RESULTS_STORE_SIZE': 3,
    'SHOW_COLLAPSED': True,
    'SQL_WARNING_THRESHOLD': 100, # milliseconds
}
```

i have body html tag
i think issue about internal ip but i cannot figure out what should it be
i put every ip from ifconfig
i use command runserver 0.0.0.0:8080

please help

after that i put ip of my computer ip

```
INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1','54.169.6.68','0.0.0.0','172.31.14.155','192.168.0.71','192.168.159.1')
i get error with rsplit() so i remove 'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': custom_show_toolbar,
```

it work but tool bar not show